# Java - URLConnection returning error code 500

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

So I am attempting to send a request to my website and read the returned response (JSON Array)
Example website output:

```
[
  "xxx",
  "xxx",
  "xxx",
  "xxx",
  "xxx"
]
```

This is my code to request and read it->

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("example.com/getJsonResponse");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)");
        System.out.println(ApiRequest.getResponse(connection));
    }
```

throws following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: example.com/getJsonResponse
```

getResponse method:

```java
    static String getResponse(URLConnection connection) throws IOException{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        return ((builder.toString() != null) ? builder.toString() : "null");
    }
```

(I've tested the method above using a pastebin paste and it worked fine)

So, the website is returning a JSON response fine when I visit it manually.

Any additional info needed let me know.